# What tool should I use to view details of GET and POST requests that are happening clientside via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I am trying to simulate a POST that is occurring on a web page via AJAX. Is there a tool where I can log the GET/POST requests so I can see exactly what is being sent by my browser?

I use Firebug, but not sure if there is a place on that app where I can view the transactions.

Please let me know the best way to go about this.

Comment: The [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) plugin for Firefox will show you *all* HTTP requests, which is sometimes useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "Net" tab in firebug console to see all the transactions along with the response & request data. Take a look at - http://getfirebug.com/network

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's developer tools has this functionality built in.  I'm using the beta channel of chrome, and to see the information, right click in your page and select "inspect element"

This will bring up the element inspecter, on which you can select the "Network" tab.  Once there, refresh your page and it will track all network activity and allow you to see the full transaction of each request.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug certainly provides this info...[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Windows [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) can observe/break/record/replay requests system wide.